# Pause youtube video on hidden Div using easytabs.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I am using [easytabs.js](http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/) to display some content. On one of the tabs is a youtube video with a custom image. The youtube video plays when the custom image is clicked. However I would like the youtube video to pause when one of the other tabs are clicked.

The test page is here: http://toddyhotpants.com/test/

If anyone has any ideas I would love to hear them!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you display the relevant source code in your question? Many people will not click unknown links to websites. Are you using youtubes API? If not then i recommend you look into using it as you will have more control of the player. https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started

Answer (score 0):

The YouTube video player has a JavaScript APi you can use to work with videos loaded on your page. 
You can find the docs here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference

As you can see there, add this to the video URL when you load it: &enablejsapi
Then when it is loaded it will call the onYoutubePlayerReady call back after which player will be available for you to call player.playVideo() and player.pauseVideo().

Let me know how it goes.

UPDATE:
Here is the example, this should pause a video after a tab is switched with easytabs.
I got the easytabs code from their site and it has jQuery so I assume that is a requirement and you already have it.
Remember to change the container ID for your tab div in the code, and set any easytab options you need to set.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var yPlayer = false;
    function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
        yPlayer = document.getElementById(playerId);
    }

    $('#YOUR-TAB-CONTAINER-ID-HERE')
      .easytabs({
        //put your options here
      })
      .bind('easytabs:after', function(e, tab){
        if ( ! tab.hasClass('active') && ! tab.hasClass('collapsed') ) {
            yPlayer.pauseVideo();
        }
      });
</script>
```

UPDATE 2:
Based on your comment I've come up with this:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var player = false;

        var tag = document.createElement('script');
        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
            height: '670',
            width: '470',
            videoId: 'nsjPrsmsll0 '
            });

            $('#YOUR-TAB-CONTAINER-ID-HERE')
            .easytabs({
                //put your options here
            })
            .bind('easytabs:after', function(e, tab){
                if ( ! tab.hasClass('active') && ! tab.hasClass('collapsed') ) {
                    player.pauseVideo();
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Replace your youtube video iframe with the this:  and use the JS code I provided.

Comment: Thanks, are you able to point me to a working version as I'm a novice with this stuff and seeing it implemented somewhere would be really helpful

Comment: I am on an iPad right now but when I get home later I will add an example for. I have used it before so I should be able to come up with one pretty easily if someone else hasn't by then. I did find this if it helps: http://help.webflow.com/how-to-control-youtube-video-using-javascript

Comment: This will show you how to add the player to your page https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started

Comment: Thank you CokaCola - if you could add an example that would be super.

Comment: Alright I added an example that should work. Might need a bit of modifying for your setup. If it works be sure to mark my answer as accepted! Let me know if you have any trouble with it.

Comment: Thank you for your help Coka - however I am still struggling a bit

if I use the iframe like so:

`<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="670" height="470"    src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/nsjPrsmsll0 enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com"frameborder="0"></iframe>`

and insert your javascript where "#bottom-tab4" is the tab container I am still not getting the video to pause when clicking one of the other tabs.  Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: I don't think it will work with an iframe, you'll need to embed it. I will update the answer with another example.

Comment: There appears to be a typo in your reply - do you mean replace the iframe with this `<div id="ytplayer"></div>` ? Which is what I have done and the player is not appearing in the tab. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: And I have replaced '#YOUR-TAB-CONTAINER-ID-HERE' with '#bottom-tab4'